# How to remove duplicated rows in MS Access DB using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a DB as follow:

```
Event ID       Date         Season
  001       03/11/2014        1
  001       03/11/2014        1
  002       10/11/2014        2
  002       10/11/2014        2
  001       07/07/2015        3
```

Desired Output:

```
Event ID       Date         Season
  001       03/11/2014        1
  002       10/11/2014        2
  001       07/07/2015        3
```

Is it possible to use SQL in MS-Access to reach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to use a temporary table, delete all the rows, and then re-insert:

```
select distinct t.*
into temp_t
from t;

delete * from t;

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_t;
```